# re-exporting module (mongoose) in nodejs / commonjs with coffeescript (zappa)

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mongoose

I'm using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com)@2.0.4 and I thought about neatly abstracting away the `mongoose.connect()` call in a module.

So using nodejs, I expected the following to work:
In `myMongoose.coffee`:

```
mongoose = require 'mongoose'
mongoose.connect 'mongodb://localhost/test'
@exports = mongoose
```

and to use it in: `MyModel.coffee`

```
mongoose = require 'myMongoose'
console.log mongoose #Prints massive object (including Schema)
Schema = mongoose.Schema
console.log Schema # undefined
```

Why would accessing a sub-element (technically a constructor function, I think) like Schema not work? Even adding `@exports.Schema = mongoose.Schema` to myMongoose.coffee doesn't fix things.

Comment: try `module.exports = mongoose`

Comment: wow, that seems to work. I thought module.exports and exports were exactly the same? can you explain the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set

`module.exports = mongoose`

You cannot overwrite `exports` with a new object. You can only add properties to `exports`.

This is because your module is actually the following :

```
(function(require, module, exports, process) {
  // your code
})();
```

`exports` is just a parameter, re-assigning it does nothing.

So if you want to overwrite exports use `module.exports`. If you want to extend `exports` use `exports.Foo`

However if you do overwrite `module.exports` it's safest to continue writing to `module.exports` instead of `exports`

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Raynos' answer, but there's something more that you should know:

```
@ is exports  # true!
```

So when you write `@exports = mongoose`, that's equivalent to `exports.exports = mongoose`!

It would probably be more intuitive for `@` to point to `module`, but then, it's handy to be able to export a bunch of stuff with `@`, especially if you want to run the same code in the browser (where `@` would point to `window` and you'd merrily populate the global scope).

Comment: I thought `@ is this # true`, so is this === exports? Thanks for the answer, but this is still a little confusing. ;)

Comment: @rdrey Yep. In the browser, in the outermost scope, `this` is `window`; while in a Node module, in the outermost scope, `this` is `exports`. (If you want to make something global, you have to attach it to `global`.)